# Shared Object for .pyc-files in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.4

**Edited** (to clarify the question):

I have a python 2.4 script with a package including many .py-files. .Pyc files are created automatically.

Can I make just one single .pyc-file out of the many .pyc-files?

The customer should not get the .py-files. And he should just get one single .pyc-file in the best case.

Comment: How is it problem? Does it slow down your system? Otherwise, don't look in the directory of the package and just use the package in your Python scripts.

Comment: Why are you using such an ancient python version?!

Comment: Because I have to. I wanted to open a new thread, because I did not undestand my task correctly at first and consequently this thread beacame kind of a mess. I would like better to close this thread and open the other one.

Comment: @user1765274 It's not a thread, it's a question. Feel free to ask another at will. Do note that if the question isn't noticably different to this one, however, it will just be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: If you're trying to distribute a `.pyc` file instead of the `.py` file to protect your IP, be aware that distributing `.pyc` files is not a solution since they can easily be rreverse engineered.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Python 3.2+, these files will be placed in [a `__pycache__` directory](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/#proposal).

In earlier versions, I don't believe there is a way to change Python's behaviour (although the PEP does say that the functionality [may be backported to 2.7](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/#implementation-strategy) - this didn't happen) - but you might be able to configure your file manager to hide `.pyc` files.

Other than that, you could clean out these files with a bash script or something like that, as they can be generated each time the program is run.

In general, I'd recommend just leaving them be.

Comment: Thanks.
Are there any other suggestion by anyone?

Comment: I'm still wondering, if there is a possibility to make one single .pyc-file out of the many .pyc-files ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not 100% sure **why** you'd want to do this, but one way is to zip up all the *.pyc files, and then use the [zipimport](http://docs.python.org/library/zipimport.html) mechanism which has been around since Py2.3.

Taken from example at bottom of page:

```
$ unzip -l /tmp/example.zip
Archive:  /tmp/example.zip
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
     8467  11-26-02 22:30   jwzthreading.py
 --------                   -------
     8467                   1 file
$ ./python
Python 2.3 (#1, Aug 1 2003, 19:54:32)
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(0, '/tmp/example.zip')  # Add .zip file to front of path
>>> import jwzthreading
>>> jwzthreading.__file__
'/tmp/example.zip/jwzthreading.py'
```